# python parse json data in a for loop

Tags: python, json

*i'm trying to parse my data from json.
I have a function that loads all data...*
Data are like this:

```
devices_infos = get_devices()

    {
  "page" : 0,
  "size" : 20,
  "totalCount" : 2,
  "data" : [ {
    "namespace" : "android",
    "id" : "0000001111111",
    "creationTs" : 1516216756819,
    "name" : "Eric's phone",
    "description" : "This device was auto registered by [mqtt] ",
    "tags" : [ ],
    "properties" : { },
    "lastUpdateTs" : 1518610495832,
    "connected" : false,
    "path" : [ ],
    "metadata" : {
      "api_key_id" : "XXX000XXX000XXX",
      "connection_start_time" : "2018-02-14T12:14:04.778Z",
      "mqtt_version" : 4,
      "mqtt_username" : "json+device",
      "mqtt_timeout" : 20,
      "remote_addr" : "00.00.00.00/PORT"
    },
    "groupId" : "root",
    "groupPath" : "/"
  }, {
    "namespace" : "sensor",
    "id" : "temp001",
    "creationTs" : 1520415684605,
    "name" : "mySensor001",
    "description" : "moisture sensor",
    "tags" : [ "france", "lyon" ],
    "properties" : {
      "manufacturer" : "miel",
      "model" : "MoistureSensorV3"
    },
    "lastUpdateTs" : 1520415684605,
    "connected" : false,
    "path" : [ ],
    "groupId" : "root",
    "groupPath" : "/"
  } ]
```

I would like to extract the name of the devices via a for loop like this:

```
if devices_infos is not None:
    print('Devices are: ')
      for each in devices_infos['data'][0]['name']:
        print (each)
else:
    print("[!] Request failed")
```

This only print me the first device, ie `Eric's phone` , i would like to have too `mySensor001`.

Comment: ['data'][0] means the first element (index zero)

Comment: yeah i know, but if i put ['data']['name'] it doesn't work, it would be an integer not a string. Otherwise i see your solution below, it works for me.

Comment: `['data']['name']` does not work because it applies to the list itself not the list elements. The `['blabla']` selector is for object key/value pairs like `{"a": 42}` and does not apply to lists, for lists the `[ ]` operator is directly accessing an index (first element, second element, ...). Example by Pradam is a list comprehension which another way to access elements in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the [0]

```
  for device in devices_infos['data']:
      name = device['name']
```

[...] means array in a JSON context, so you must iterate (loop) on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> import json
>>> str = '''
...  {
...   "page" : 0,
...   "size" : 20,
...   "totalCount" : 2,
...   "data" : [ {
...     "namespace" : "android",
...     "id" : "0000001111111",
...     "creationTs" : 1516216756819,
...     "name" : "Eric's phone",
...     "description" : "This device was auto registered by [mqtt] ",
...     "tags" : [ ],
...     "properties" : { },
...     "lastUpdateTs" : 1518610495832,
...     "connected" : false,
...     "path" : [ ],
...     "metadata" : {
...       "api_key_id" : "XXX000XXX000XXX",
...       "connection_start_time" : "2018-02-14T12:14:04.778Z",
...       "mqtt_version" : 4,
...       "mqtt_username" : "json+device",
...       "mqtt_timeout" : 20,
...       "remote_addr" : "00.00.00.00/PORT"
...     },
...     "groupId" : "root",
...     "groupPath" : "/"
...   }, {
...     "namespace" : "sensor",
...     "id" : "temp001",
...     "creationTs" : 1520415684605,
...     "name" : "mySensor001",
...     "description" : "moisture sensor",
...     "tags" : [ "france", "lyon" ],
...     "properties" : {
...       "manufacturer" : "miel",
...       "model" : "MoistureSensorV3"
...     },
...     "lastUpdateTs" : 1520415684605,
...     "connected" : false,
...     "path" : [ ],
...     "groupId" : "root",
...     "groupPath" : "/"
...   } ]}'''
>>> d = json.loads(str)
>>> d
{u'totalCount': 2, u'data': [{u'lastUpdateTs': 1518610495832L, u'description': u'This device was auto registered by [mqtt] ', u'tags': [], u'namespace': u'android', u'creationTs': 1516216756819L, u'properties': {}, u'connected': False, u'groupPath': u'/', u'groupId': u'root', u'path': [], u'metadata': {u'api_key_id': u'XXX000XXX000XXX', u'remote_addr': u'00.00.00.00/PORT', u'mqtt_username': u'json+device', u'mqtt_timeout': 20, u'connection_start_time': u'2018-02-14T12:14:04.778Z', u'mqtt_version': 4}, u'id': u'0000001111111', u'name': u"Eric's phone"}, {u'lastUpdateTs': 1520415684605L, u'description': u'moisture sensor', u'tags': [u'france', u'lyon'], u'namespace': u'sensor', u'creationTs': 1520415684605L, u'properties': {u'model': u'MoistureSensorV3', u'manufacturer': u'miel'}, u'connected': False, u'groupPath': u'/', u'groupId': u'root', u'path': [], u'id': u'temp001', u'name': u'mySensor001'}], u'page': 0, u'size': 20}
>>> for i in d['data']:
...     print(i['name'])
...
Eric's phone
mySensor001
```

I hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: You are always welcome. Please do not forget to select the answer that resolved your issue. It will be helpful to all who reaches your question with same query.